# Optimize classifier for multiclass Brier score instead of accuracy

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, multiclass-classification

I am more interested in optimizing my multiclass problem with Brier score instead of accuracy. To achieve that, I am evaluating my classifiers with the results of predict_proba() like:

```
import numpy as np

probs = np.array(
[    [1, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 1]]
)

targets = np.array(
    [[0.9, 0.05, 0.05],
    [0.1, 0.8, 0.1],
    [0.7, 0.2, 0.1],
    [0.1, 0.9, 0],
    [0, 0, 1],
    [0.5, 0.3, 0.2],
    [0.1, 0.5, 0.4],
    [0.34, 0.33, 0.33]]
)


def brier_multi(targets, probs):
    return np.mean(np.sum((probs - targets) ** 2, axis=1))


brier_multi(targets, probs)
```

Is it possible to optimize scikit-learns classifier directly during training for multiclass Brier score instead of accuracy?

Edit:

```
...
pipe = Pipeline(
    steps=[
        ("preprocessor", preprocessor),
        ("selector", None),
        ("classifier", model.get("classifier")),
    ]
)

def brier_multi(targets, probs):
    ohe_targets = OneHotEncoder().fit_transform(targets.reshape(-1, 1))
    return np.mean(np.sum(np.square(probs - ohe_targets), axis=1))

brier_multi_loss = make_scorer(
    brier_multi,
    greater_is_better=False,
    needs_proba=True,
)

search = GridSearchCV(
    estimator=pipe,
    param_grid=model.get("param_grid"),
    scoring=brier_multi_loss,
    cv=3,
    n_jobs=-1,
    refit=True,
    verbose=3,
)
search.fit(X_train, y_train)
...
```

leads to nan as score

```
/home/andreas/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py:969: UserWarning: One or more of the test scores are non-finite: [nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]
  warnings.warn(
```

Comment: How are you currently optimizing?

Comment: GridSearchCV's scoring parameter is None (default), which I suppose is accuracy.

Comment: Set `error_score='raise'` in the search object and report the full traceback.  Provide a sample dataset if you're able, and working values for `param_grid` and `model['classifier']`.

Comment: How can I share my dataset? It's just 4 mb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're already aware of the `scoring` parameter, so you just need to wrap your `brier_multi` into the format expected by `GridSearchCV`.  There's a utility for that, `make_scorer`:

```py
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer

neg_mc_brier_score = make_scorer(
    brier_multi,
    greater_is_better=False,
    needs_proba=True,
)

GridSearchCV(..., scoring=neg_mc_brier_score)
```

See the [User Guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#defining-your-scoring-strategy-from-metric-functions) and [the docs for `make_scorer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html).

Unfortunately, that won't run, because your version of the scorer expects a one-hot-encoded targets array, whereas sklearn multiclass will send `y_true` as a 1d array.  As a hack to make sure the rest works, you can modify:

```py
def brier_multi(targets, probs):
    ohe_targets = OneHotEncoder().fit_transform(targets.reshape(-1, 1))
    return np.mean(np.sum(np.square(probs - ohe_targets), axis=1))
```

but I would encourage you to make this more robust (what if the classes aren't just `0, 1, ..., n_classes-1`?).

For what it's worth, sklearn has a PR in progress to add multiclass Brier score: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/22046 (be sure to see the linked PR18699, as it has the beginning of development and review).

Comment: Hm, it worked for me with the iris dataset.

Comment: It seems like, targets from brier_multi() is a pd.Series. 'ohe_targets = OneHotEncoder().fit_transform(np.array(targets).reshape(-1, 1))' is working...

Comment: Ah, OK. For a series, you can drop the reshape instead of numpy'ifying it. For robustness, maybe use the sklearn utility `check_array` together with reshape.